# PrimeNg, Dialog, Modal : When closing the modal the overlay stays

Tags: angular, primeng

I have implemented in an angular component a PrimeNg table.

When clicking on an image (thumbnail) within one of the column I open a dialog as modal to show a bigger sized image.

Everything is working as expected until I close the dialog.

The modal overlay and dialog-mask stays...

Any idea why?

```
<div *ngIf="breeds && breeds.length >0">
  <p-table #dt_breed [globalFilterFields]="['name']"
           [paginator]="true"
           [rows]="5"
           [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
           [value]="breeds"
           currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
           responsiveLayout="scroll" styleClass="p-datatable-striped">
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="p-card-title">Breeds</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <button (click)="clear(dt_breed)" class="p-button-outlined" icon="pi pi-filter-slash" pButton
                  pTooltip="Clear filter"></button>
          <span class="p-input-icon-left">
                    <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                    <input (input)="dt_breed.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value, 'contains')"
                           pInputText placeholder="Search keyword"
                           type="text"/>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th pSortableColumn="id">Id
          <p-sortIcon field="id"></p-sortIcon>
        </th>
        <th pSortableColumn="name">Name
          <p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon>
        </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-breed pTemplate="body">
      <tr>
        <td>{{breed.id}}</td>
        <td>{{breed.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <img (click)="showDialog(breed.image_link,breed.name)" [alt]="breed.image_link"
               src="{{breed.image_link}}"
               style="vertical-align: middle" width="64"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft">
      <p-button (onClick)="add()" icon="pi pi-plus" styleClass="p-button-text" type="button"></p-button>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorright">
      <p-button icon="pi pi-sync" styleClass="p-button-text" type="button"></p-button>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
  <p-dialog [(visible)]="visible" [dismissableMask]="true" [header]="visible_breed.text">
    <img
      [alt]="visible_breed.url"
      [src]="visible_breed.url"
      style="vertical-align: middle;" width="512"/>
  </p-dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: Not reproducible: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k882wv-23zqxx?file=src/app/demo/table-basic-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you add code for the showDialog() from ts file? You might have changed the visible to false when you click on the column second time

Comment: The method only do ```this.visible=true```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and i have temporarly solved adding a viechild and setting to false the maskvisible property of Dialog when i close it.

```
@Viewchild("dlg") _dialog: Dialog;
```

and on close function:

```
this._dialog.maskVisible = false;
```